# Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger issue with black / blank screen on any device for GenyMotion

Tags: android, virtualbox, appcelerator, genymotion

I can not get genymotion to throw up a device past the black screen.  The logcat file states:

"Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger" over and over.  MAC osx - anyone been able to fix this issue??  Using the Samsung Galaxy S5 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920 device.

My network settings in the virtualbox adapater are all checking out - went down that route already.

Thanks
[Screenshot of device with black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sbiz.png)

Comment: Yes, sometimes this happens to me. I just wait a little bit or restart the simulator and it works. Not sure what it is =/

Comment: waited forever- no dice :-/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue; spent about an hour fiddling... Then I deleted the virtual and re-created one (in about 2 minutes). It started up with no issues, and the SurfaceFlinger wait hasn't reappeared... Result.